# Compare String Arrays of Different Sizes

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq

I have two string arrays that I want to compare to each other. The one array (sProdList) will always be a set size (16 values), the other (sProd) might be 16, but it might be more or less values. I want to see if sProd contains any of the values in sProdList.

I'm using the below LINQ to try this out:

```
If Array.Exists(sProd, Function(x As String) sProdList.Contains(x)) Then
```

The idea being that if the current value of sProd is in sProdList it goes into the If statement, otherwise it skips over it.

When debugging my code I see that the value of x is 24, I'm not sure where it's getting this value from as neither of my arrays have 24 items.

Code is below, any help would be appreciated:

```
    'Separate out Product Names
    Dim sProd() As String = {}
    Dim sInst() As String = {}
    Dim sProdList() As String = {"Auto", "Chequing", "GIC", "Mutual Funds", "Real Estate", "RIF", "RSP", "Savings", "Shares", "Stock", "TFSA", "CCard", "Guar", "Loan", "Loc", "Mortgage"}
    sProd = objNode.InnerText.Split(",")

    objNode = Nothing

    objNode = objXMl.SelectSingleNode("//Inst")

    sInst = objNode.InnerText.Split(",")

    Dim instPos As Integer = 0
    For Each st As String In sProdList
        If Array.Exists(sProd, Function(x As String) sProdList.Contains(x)) Then
            If sInst(instPos) = "PCCU" Then
                img = My.Resources.check
            ElseIf sInst(instPos) <> "PCCU" OrElse sInst(instPos) = "" Then
                img = My.Resources.exclamation
            Else
                img = My.Resources.redX
            End If

            dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {st, imageToByteArray(img)})
            instPos += 1
        End If
    Next

        dgProduct.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: Do you get the results you expect?  I wouldn't fully trust the debugger when using Linq methods like `Contains`.  Linq adds wrappers around the source collection that can provide misleading information when debugging.

Comment: No, currently my sProd has 4 values, 3 are within sProdList and one isn't. It shouldn't be entering the If statement for the 4th value but it is.

Comment: Obligatory note that you should turn on Option Strict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over `sProdList` but checking *the whole list* each time.

You can just use the Linq `Contains` method to see if `sProd` contains the string:

```
For Each st As String In sProdList
    If sProd.Contains(st) Then
        ....
```

Comment: Bluh, it's always the simplest code isn't it? Thanks for the help :)!

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating sProdList, so you don't want to compare all of them within the loop, but you can use `.Intersect` to change to loop to just loop over the ones that are in both like this:

```
For Each st As String In sProdList.Intersect(sProd)
    If sInst(instPos) = "PCCU" Then
        img = My.Resources.check
    ElseIf sInst(instPos) <> "PCCU" OrElse sInst(instPos) = "" Then
        img = My.Resources.exclamation
    Else
        img = My.Resources.redX
    End If

    dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {st, imageToByteArray(img)})
    instPos += 1
Next If
```

Also, you can further use LINQ to do create your query and feed that directly to `dgProduct.DataSource` rather than using `DataTable` as a wrapper like this:

```
Dim imgs = sInst.Select(Function(i) imageToByteArray(If(i = "PCCU", My.Resources.check, If((i <> "PCCU" OrElse i = ""), My.Resources.exclamation, My.Resources.redX))))
dgProduct.DataSource = sProdList.Intersect(sProd).Zip(imgs, Function(product, image) New From { product, image })
```